# Choose sources.. button in intellij doesn't work

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, jar

I have ALS.class decoded and I want to see initial source file. I've managed to download .jar with sources (even though **Download sources** button is broken):

[image]

Now I select file:

[image]

and nothing happens. I tried closing and re-navigating to ALS class, but this doesn't help. Any ideas?

PS: jar with sources is visible in the project structure:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I was missing Scala support for Intellij, an extension from JetBrains. After I've installed it, everything worked.